# Saving string to SQLite many times consumes a ridiculous amount of disk space?

Tags: django, sqlite

Through my front-end I allow users to edit posts with an auto-save-function. Every update of the post is saved to the DB. On edit the instance from the last save is updated via a `PUT` request.

The amount of space this is consuming however is quite ridiculous. Disregarding, if the updated string gets longer or shorter the space only goes up. My local SQLite file has now more than 500MB.

The relevant view in django is verbose but pretty standard I'd say:

```
class PostDetail(APIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsOwnerOrReadOnly,
        IsOwnerOrPublishedOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        is_published = self.request.query_params.get('is_published', None)
        if is_published and is_published == 'false':
            queryset.filter(is_published=False)
        if is_published and is_published == 'true':
            queryset.filter(is_published=True)
        return queryset

    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), uuid=self.kwargs.get('post_uuid', None))
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj

    def put(
        self, 
        request, 
        post_uuid, 
        format=None):
        post = self.get_object()
        serializer = PostUpdateSerializer(post, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

I can't really wrap my head around how to debug this? This is why I'm turning to SO. Any tips?

Comment: The first step with any SQL database is to try [`VACUUM`](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html). See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The for the sake of documenting this:

My problem was, that I was using a profiling tool called django-silk. This was saving every SQL query and DB request as well as a profiling record. This consumes a ridiculous amount of disk space.

To analyse the database I had to switch to postgres.